# Native .NET version of Rsync for commercial application available?

Tags: c#, .net, rsync

Currently we are evaluating whether it is possible to provide **[rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)** support to an application we sell.

I did a Google search and found some references:

- "[Native Window version of rsync](http://www.backupcentral.com/phpBB2/two-way-mirrors-of-external-mailing-lists-3/backuppc-21/native-window-version-of-rsync-94197/)" - A discussion about an implementation but without any code.
- "[Has anyone wrapped the rsync algorithm in C#-callable package?](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/234086-has-anyone-wrapped-rsync-algorithm-c-callable-package)" - A discussion that links to a weblog that is no longer available.

Since it is a commercial application, we want something that is *not* GPL licensed.

**Question:**

Are you aware of a package to get rsync functions for copying files, which we can ship with a commercial Windows application?

Bonus would be if the rsync functions require no extra installation on the system, just XCOPY and you're done.

Comment: Just as a remark, the GPL does not hinder you to use a lib in a commercial application since you are not required to publish your own code under it.

Comment: Thanks, tDo, I am kind of a novice in that licensing stuff; I thought LGPL is for that.

Comment: @tDo: take care distinguishing between 'commercial' and 'proprietary': there are many commercial applications released under GPL (like MySQL).  Proprietary applications can't use GPL libraries, only LGPL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [.Net port of rsync](http://github.com/kolosy/rsync.net) at github. It looks like it's only the client part.

You'll need [cwRsync](http://www.itefix.no/cwrsync/) to install a cygwin version of the server.