# Methods to transfer files from Windows server to linux server

Tags: windows, linux, samba, file-sharing

I need to transfer webserver-log-like-files containing periodically from windows production servers in the US to linux servers here in India. The files are ~4 MB in size each and I get about 1 file per minute. I can take about 5 mins lag between the files getting written in windows and them being available in the linux machines. I am a bit confused between the various options here as I am quite inexperienced in such design:

1. I am thinking of writing a service in C#.NET which will periodically archive, compress and send them over to the linux machines. These files are pretty compressible. WinRAR can convert 32 MB of these files into a 1.2 MB archive. So that should solve the network transfer speed issue. But then how exactly do I transfer files to linux? I could mount linux drive on windows server using samba, or should I create an ftp server, or send the file serialized as a POST request. Which one would be good? Also, I have to minimize the load on the windows server.
2. Mount the windows drive on linux instead. I could use the mount command or I could use samba here (What are the pros and cons of these two?). I can then write the compressing and copying part in linux itself.

I don't trust the internet connection to be very stable, so there should be a good retry mechanism and failure protection too. What are the potential gotchas in these situations, and other points that I must be worried about?

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: should'nt this go to superuser?

Answer (score 3):

RAR is bad. Stick to 7zip or bzip2. Transfer it using ssh, probably with rsync since it can be link-failure-tolerant.

Comment: With the 7z format, you can actually specify the algorithm used. PPMd is a very fast and effective algorithm for compressing plain text files. This is ideal for large collections of log files.

Comment: RAR is generally Linux unfriendly, and since you know the content type you can pick a more-efficient specific algorithm (which unfortunately is not gzip/deflate).

Comment: @Dean.. Thanks for the tip :). But our windows code is all in C# and they supprt GZip natively so I'll use gz if I go with option 1. For option 2, I'll use perl fo create archive. In that case I'll use 7z.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222030/how-do-i-create-7-zip-archives-with-net

Comment: Thanks for the link Ignacio... ok, I can use 7z in .NET with the SDK. But what about my main question? Is there any clear cut winner between options 1 and 2? :$

Comment: No, they're both terrible ideas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253259/native-net-version-of-rsync-for-commercial-application-available

Comment: FYI: 916MB of SQL backups compressed gzip=7.41MB 7z(PPMd)=0.26MB - if over the wire speed is your issue consider how you are compressing things.

Comment: Wow! That's some compression! But even if I use rsync, I'll have to do some kind of mounting, right?

Comment: Nope. rsync is perfectly capable of running over SSH.

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP can help you transfer files from Windows to Linux in batch with script. Then configure Windows Task Scheduler to run the script periodically.

I learnt from this post step by step: https://techglimpse.com/batch-script-automate-file-transfer-winscp/